# Is there any way to make VS Code correctly handle Android packages?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to study and develop android projects. I am using the Code Runner extension that handles C/C++/Java and many more file management and allows me to jump between files and find source of objects/classes etc.

But it also gives a lot of errors because it cannot resolve the android packages. The error is:

```
<PackageName> cannot be resolved to a typeJava(16777218)
```

Is there any way (extensions, options, etc.) to make it handle packages from android or make these packages behave like Java packages?

Answer (score 0):

yaa there is called "Android" which is under the name of "adelphes"